# R : understanding simplified script with brackets or hooks?

Tags: r, dataframe, hook, brackets

I would like to understand how really works this script :

`y <- y[keep, , keep.lib.sizes=FALSE]`

in :
`keep <- rowSums(cpm(y)>1) >= 3
y <- y[keep, , keep.lib.sizes=FALSE]`

I do know `d.f[a,b]` but I can not find R-doc for `d.f[a, ,b]`.

I tried "brackets", "hooks", "commas"... :-(

(Sometimes I would prefer that one does not simplifie his R script !)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to read the documentation of the specific package. It seems to come from `edgeR` (see https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/edgeR/inst/doc/edgeRUsersGuide.pdf). Yes, google is your friend (I found the ref in ~30 seconds, with "keep.lib.sizes" as keyword...)

Comment: I already spent thousands of hours in this official 104 p book. In this book it is assumed that we are "R" masters ! But I am not. And I like to understand what I am doing. This is why I was looking for help here. Save me from this kind of comment please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscripting data.Frames takes two values: `df[rows, columns]`. Any third value are optional arguments that you can use to subscript.

The most common of those is `drop=FALSE` as in `df[1:18, 3, drop = FALSE]`. This is done because when you subset just one column of a data.frame, it will lose the data.frame class. In your specific case, it seems like you are using another object that looks like a data.frame but with added functionalities from the bioconductor package. A look at the methods for those will tell you how these work.

Comment: Thanks for this explanantion. I was missing this keyword "subscripting".

Comment: Space between two commas is analogous to `df[a, 1:ncol(x), drop = FALSE]` which will not drop to vector if `ncol(x)` is 1.